# iOS 11+: is there a way to temporarily mute sound output?

Tags: ios, audio

#### Use case:

- Spotify runs an ad.  You know how obnoxious those can be.
- I **somehow temporarily mute for say 60 secs** (duration should be parametrized).
- After 60 seconds, volume level comes back to normal, hopefully past ads.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [<sub>[image]</sub> **Workflow**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workflow/id915249334?mt=8&at=1001lwpF) using the following workflow. Workflows can be run from a share menu, **Today widget** or by opening the app.

Since Workflow was acquired by Apple and integrated into iOS 12, it should also be possible with Shortcuts in iOS 12.

- Download [<sub>[image]</sub> **Workflow**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workflow/id915249334?mt=8&at=1001lwpF), then install this workflow [<sub>[image]</sub> Mute Temporarily](https://workflow.is/workflows/3da4b23ff9094432b36a9542a36ec64a).

  [image]

Comment: Great idea!  I just added this to my iPhone X iOS 12 as a Siri shortcut!

Comment: Hey, that looks pretty good. I am still on iOS 10.3 actually (misstyped that above) and I can install the app but it doesn't have the Get Device Details, so I guess the API is missing.  Still, upvoting you.

Comment: worked great once I updated to iOS 11.4.